# Class 'Dropbox\Client' not found ( Laravel )

Tags: laravel

I'm use Dropbox image hosting, I downloaded Dropbox's install league / flysystem-dropbox package, but when I ran the code below it crashed

> Class 'Dropbox \ Client' not found.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Dropbox\Client;
use Dropbox\WriteMode;
class ExpenseController extends Controller
{
    public function postExpenseAdd( Request $request ){
        $Client = new Client(env('DROPBOX_TOKEN'), env('DROPBOX_SECRET'));
        $file = fopen(public_path('img/admin.png'), 'rb');
        $size = filesize(public_path('img/admin.png'));
        $dropboxFileName = '/myphoto4.png';
        $Client->uploadFile($dropboxFileName,WriteMode::add(),$file, $size);
        $links['share'] = $Client->createShareableLink($dropboxFileName);
        $links['view'] = $Client->createTemporaryDirectLink($dropboxFileName);
        print_r($links);die;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you already do?  Did you install it with composer? Dd you add the package to your config/app.php? You need to provide more info to get a right answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will not be an answer to your current question (at least not with the package you are currently working with), but this might get you back on the right track:

The `league/flysystem-dropbox` won't work anymore as this package uses the API v1 version of dropbox that has meanwhile been [deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/) (API v1 will be completely unavailable on September 28, 2017).

Since the package is not maintaned anymore and will not receive an update to the API v2 version you should take a look at the [srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2](https://github.com/srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2) package.

In short: you can run `composer require srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2` to get started with the new version of the API.

Comment: To my mind this is the best way to respond in first place. It would not be helpful  to give the solution for the deprecated  code or package. Thank again